# How does one POST JSON encoded content in tsung?

Tags: tsung

Here's what I have:

```
 <session name="es_load" probability="100" type="ts_http">
         <request subst="true">
            <http url='/access.log' version='1.0'
              contents='{&quot;username&quot;=&quot;rsss&quot;,&quot;password&quot;=&quot;pass&quot;}'
            content_type='application/json' method='POST'>
            </http>
         </request>
  </session>
```

I don't see this even getting posted on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to locust.io and couldn't be happier!

Answer (score 0):

```
<request>
  <http url="/portal/v2/portal" method="POST" version="1.1" contents='{
    "status": "online",
    "language": "en",
    "preference": {
      "optIn": "1"
    }
  }'>
    <http_header name="authorization" value="Bearer token"/>
  </http>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'contents' attribute use the "contents_from_file" attribute just like below,

```
   <request subst="true">
     <http url="https://**API**" method="POST"
     **contents_from_file**="file.json">
                    
     <http_header name="accept" value="*/*"/>
     <http_header name="content-type" value="application/json"/>
     <http_header name="authorization" value="%%_token%%"/>
     
    </http>
   </request>
```

**Note:** In this 'file.json' provide the data properly and save it.